# Replicate html positioning without using CSS float

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, css-float

I'm trying to replicate this [Float Example](https://codepen.io/10serna/pen/KKKYdpe) that uses the `float` property to align its content, with this [Grid and Flex Solution](https://codepen.io/10serna/pen/zYYXvGX). I want replace the `float` property everywhere  and I've been able to align every thing properly except for the `<section>` containing the `<aside>` and `<div>` boxes. Here is what it's supposed to look like:
[image: Aligned boxes using Float]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #FFA500;
}

#full {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  clear: both;
  color: #fff;
  background: #394549;
}

#division {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #214fb3;
}

aside {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background: #a6b747;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
 <section id="full">
    <aside>
      &lt;aside&gt; #a6b747
    </aside>
    &lt;section&gt; #394549
    <div id="division">
      &lt;div&gt; #6ea3da
    </div>
  </section>
```

and this is what I currently have using `position: absolute;` on the `<aside>` box. 
[image: Aligned boxes without float]

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
}

#full {
  grid-area: full;
  background: #394549;
  color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;  
}

aside {
  position: absolute;
  height: 160px;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px;  
  background: #a6b747;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

#division {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #214fb3;
}
```

```html
<section id="full">
  <aside>
    &lt;aside&gt; #a6b747
  </aside>
  &lt;section&gt; #394549
  <div id="division">
    &lt;div&gt; #6ea3da
  </div>
</section>
```

I had to mess around with the pixels to get the correct heights in a hacky way but I'm not sure how to fix width of the `<div>` and `<aside>` boxes. They should stay consistent with the first example even when resizing the windows and I'm also not sure how to align the `<section>` and `<div>` text.

Comment: Please provide your HTML + CSS code, thanks

Comment: I've added the snippets of html and css to the question. The entire code are in the codepens I mentioned in the beginning. Not sure why I was downvoted.

Comment: Not sure, it's generally because they don't have enough info to work off to answer your question. Note: I didn't downvote you. Thanks for supplying the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So by using absolute positioning on the aside you need to add suitable padding to the left for the rest of the content so it rests centered in the space on the right.

However, because you have the div going behind the aside, you can't just put that large padding directly on the section, or it will push everything inside to the right. This means that the content `<section> #394549` must go in its own container. I added margin-bottom to the new container to push the blue box down a little.

The padding I adding to the left uses `calc(33% + 64px);` in order to account for the margin on left of the aside and to fall centered nicely in the space on the right.

I also added `box-sizing: border-box;` to everything, as it makes calculating widths easier and causes percentage based sizing to behave more sensibly. You could use `content-box` (the default) instead, but you would have to adjust dimensions to account. Your original dimensions were using `border-box` reasoning so I figured that was the sensible choice to make your dimensions behave appropriately.

```css
/* added box-sizing: border-box */
* {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#full {
  grid-area: full;
  background: #394549;
  color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;  
}

aside {
  position: absolute;
  height: 160px;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px;  
  background: #a6b747;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

/* Added this container so we can put padding
   on content without effecting the blue box.
   also added margin-bottom to put a little
   space between this and the blue box */
#section-content {
  padding: 0 20px 0 calc(33% + 64px);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* added padding on the left */
#division {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px calc(33% + 64px);
  background: #214fb3;
}
```

```html
<section id="full">
  <aside>
    &lt;aside&gt; #a6b747
  </aside>
  <!--added additional container #section-content-->
  <div id="section-content">
    &lt;section&gt; #394549
  </div>
  <div id="division">
    &lt;div&gt; #6ea3da
  </div>
</section>
```